# Spark Sql Parser append additional parameter in UDF call

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I use SQL statements as input from users something like "`CASE WHEN CALL_UDF("12G", 2) < 0 THEN 4 ELSE 5 END`".

I would like to add in this string an additional parameter. 
Expected result: "`CASE WHEN CALL_UDF("12G", 2, additional_parameter) < 0 THEN 4 ELSE 5 END`".

To achieve this goal I am trying to use `SparkSqlParser` but faced problems during the implementation of this replacement. Probably someone has implemented a similar solution. Thanks.

What I have already tried:

```
val expression = parser.parseExpression("CASE WHEN CALL_UDF("12G", 2) < 0 THEN 3 ELSE 4 END")
  .transformDown {
    case expression if expression.isInstanceOf[UnresolvedFunction] && expression.asInstanceOf[UnresolvedFunction].name.funcName == "CALL_UDF" =>
      UnresolvedFunction(FunctionIdentifier("CALL_UDF"), expression.children.toList ++ Seq(parser.parseExpression("4")), false)
  }
```